# Find all rows same value in Col1 but different values in Col2

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Given a table similar to this:

```
Col1                 Col2
----                 ----
A                    A
A                    A
B                    B
C                    C
C                    D
```

I'm trying to write a query which will identify all values in Col1 which appear more than once AND have differing values in Col2.  So a query that would return only rows with C in Col1 (because there are two rows with C in Col1, and they have differing values in Col2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groupy by `col1` and take only the ones having more than 1 unique `col2`. These automatically have more than one `col1` value too.

```
select col1
from your_table
group by col1
having count(distinct col2) > 1
```

Comment: Brilliant, I didn't know you could use count(distinct) with a column you weren't grouping by.